# Visual Studio 2015 instaliation trouble

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command-prompt, fatal-error

I am attempting to download visual studios 2015. When doing so I get the below error message

[image: Visual Studio Error message]

I have done my research and tried to do the `fsutil behavior set l2l:1 l2r:1 r2l:1 r2r:1` but when I do this it tells me that the access is denied

[image: cmd access denied]

Mind you I am the admin on this computer. So my question is

1. why am I getting a fatal error on VS and
2. what are some other ways in which I can get the cmd access granted.

Comment: Try updating your system and then install it. Because I got many errors and updating my system fixed them

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 - Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory to fix upgrade problems**

The Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper is a minimal light-weight executable that installs the rest of the Visual Studio Installer. Deleting Visual Studio Installer files and then rerunning the bootstrapper might solve some update failures.

Note

Performing the following actions reinstalls the Visual Studio Installer files and resets the installation metadata.

Close the Visual Studio Installer.

Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory. Typically, the directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.

Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You might find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name that follows a vs_[Visual Studio edition]__*.exepattern. If you don't find that application, you can download the bootstrapper by going to the Visual Studio downloads page and clicking Download for your edition of Visual Studio. Then, run the executable to reset your installation metadata.

Try to install or update Visual Studio again. If the Installer continues to fail, go to the next step.

**Step 2 - Run InstallCleanup.exe to remove installation files**

As a last resort, you can remove Visual Studioto remove all installation files and product information.

Follow the instructions in Remove Visual Studio.

Rerun the bootstrapper that's described in Step 3 - Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory to fix upgrade problems.

Try to install or update Visual Studio again.